# How to find the ng-table's column summation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to find the summation of cost column from ng-table, does the tableParams have any such method to find the summation? i know there is one to find the total records in the table. I have tried looking into its documentation but i can't find one. [`Plunker here`](https://plnkr.co/edit/0XA3NbcWF91nSo0QXgkG?p=preview)

The cost should update when the records are filtered as well, for example currently i have 11 records in the table and when i look/filter for 'Server1' it should list 3 servers(which works fine) but i need the cost to be summed up and display at the top.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement a function can do the job needed, watch if the selected values are all the same and them sum the values, also if there is only one record, just show that one's cost alone

<kbd>**Plunkr Demo**</kbd>

**Code:**

```
$scope.calcCost = function(){
    var arr = [];
    var cost = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.tableParams.data, function(value){
      arr.push(value.title);
      cost = cost + parseFloat(value.cost.slice(2));
    })
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(cost);
    if(identical(arr) || arr.length === 1){ 
      return "$ "+cost;
    }else{
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Praveen does this help you?